# Why isn't the AVD launching my Android App?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm only just learning Android development.  I created a new Android Application Project in Eclipse which created a basic hello world.  Eclipse launches the the AVD but does not launch the HelloWorld app.  It managed to launch the app once.  I will try to give as much information on my setup.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- JDK 7u5 64-bit installed
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 64-bit
- Android ADT installed
- Android SDK installed

  - Android 2.3.3 (API10)

When I created a new Android Application Project I chose Build SDK: `Android 2.3.3 (API10)` and for Minimum Required SDK: `API10: Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread)`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mytest.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mytest.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have an AVD using the `Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10` target with skin `Default (WVGA800)`.  No custom properties.

I launch the `MainActivity.java` as a Android Application, the AVD launches but the HelloWorld app does not.  Here is the Eclipse Android console output:

```
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] Performing com.mytest.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android_2.3.3'
[2012-07-22 02:11:22 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_2.3.3'
```

Here's the console output when I somehow managed to get it to work:

```
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] Performing com.mytest.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android_2.3.3'
[2012-07-21 15:51:57 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_2.3.3'
[2012-07-21 15:51:58 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-07-21 15:51:58 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-07-21 15:52:06 - HelloWorld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-21 15:52:06 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-21 15:52:08 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2012-07-21 15:52:12 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2012-07-21 15:52:12 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.mytest.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-07-21 15:52:13 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mytest.helloworld/.MainActivity }
```

Remember I didn't edit anything when I created this Hello World. The only thing I entered was the name of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to boot up emulator.. then it will launch ur app.

Don't close emulator every time, start it once and run ur app by choosing this one only...

Comment: I get `WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!` and `ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\Anthony\.android\avd\Android_2.3.3.avd/snapshots.img` in the console when leaving the emulator on.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `adb devices` I did not see my AVD device listed.  It seems I need restart the adb server by running:

`adb kill-server`
`adb start-server`

I ran `adb devices` again and saw my AVD device listed.  My HelloWorld app finally ran.